# React cascading select onChange filter doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

I'm fairly new to React. Im my drawer(left side) I have several options fields. The options of the 2nd one depends on the chosen 1st one, the options of the 3rd on the chosen 2nd......

The problem is that my filter function returns an empty array.

I also tried this with the same result.

```
setNewAgents(agents.filter(x => x.age_region_id === id).map(x => (x.age_name)))
```

I'm grateful for any help.

[image]

On the first render I load all data with axios and populate the 1st field

```
 const [id, setId] = useState()
 const [selectedReg, setSelectedReg] = useState('');
 const [agents, setAgents] = useState([]);
 const [newAgents, setNewAgents] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () =>
  {
    try
    {
      const regions = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getRegions');
      const agents = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getAgents');
      etc ...
      axios.all([regions, agents, customers, stations, pumps, cameras])
        .then(axios.spread((...allData) => 
        {
          setReg(allData[0].data)
          setAgents(allData[1].data)
         etc ...
        }))
    }
    catch (err)
    {
      // Handle Error Here
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

then depending on the choice I want to populate the 2nd.

```
 function handleChange(e)
  {

     // returns the correct id
    setId(e.target.value);

     //returns empty array
    setNewAgents(agents.filter(x => x.age_region_id === id))

  }
  console.log(id)
  console.log(newAgents)
```

I use material-UI

```
return (
    <Drawer Drawer
        ...
      variant="permanent"
      anchor="left"
    >
      <Divider />

      <ListItem key='Region' disablePadding>
        <IconButton key='Region' sx={{ color: 'white' }} >
          < LanguageIcon />
        </IconButton >
        <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
          <TextField
            .... //some sx
            select
            label='Region'
            value={selectedReg}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="standard"
            SelectProps={{
              native: true,
            }}
          >
            <option value="DEFAULT"></option>
            {regions.map((reg, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={reg.reg_id}>
                {reg.reg_name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </TextField>
        </FormControl>
      </ListItem>

      <ListItem key='Agent' disablePadding>
        <IconButton key='Agent' sx={{ color: 'white' }} >
          < AccountCircleIcon />
        </IconButton >
        <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
          <TextField
              //...some sx
            select
            label='Agent'
            value={selectedReg}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="standard"
            SelectProps={{
              native: true,
            }}
          >
            <option value="DEFAULT"></option>
            {agents.map((age) => (
              <option key={age.age_id} id={age.age_id} value={age.age_name}>
                {age.age_name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </TextField>
        </FormControl>
      </ListItem>
```

UPDATE:

I narrowed down my code a little bit and created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-varahamihira-ks7yk3?file=/src/App.js).
It works but...

When the app is loaded for the first time and I choose a region it doesn't work. If I switch region a few time it works.

The question is why and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Pls check my answer below, plus you are logging newAgents to the console inside the handler which is not correct, check this copy of your sandbox i just changed it : `https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cray-noj230?file=/src/demo.js`

Comment: En als je nog hulp nodig hebt, kunnen wij dan pair coden :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the changeHandler, first you set the id in setId setter, at this point id is null, i recommend you to do this:

```
 function handleChange(e)
  {
    const selectedId = e.target.value;
    const filteredAgents = agents.filter(x => x.age_region_id === selectedId);
     
    if (filteredAgents?.length) {
      setNewAgents(filteredAgents);
     }

  }
```

then you don't need the state of id at all.

Or if you need it then just keep the setter id inside changeHandler and then make another useEffect to keep track on the id , based on id you have then to make your filter, it works in both cases , but since i don't see any use case of id state then i would use the first option as the code above

Comment: geen dank hoor!
Proost!